# Limt and Convergence of Integral

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

1. If $\lim_{x \to \infty} x f(x)=0$, then $\int_a^\infty f(x) dx$ converges, where $a>0$. Is this statement true or is there any counterexample? I have seen the converse of this statement which is true when the function is monotonic.
2. If $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=1$, then $\int_a^\infty f(x) dx$ may or may not converge. It is easy to find an example where the function diverges: $f(x)=1+\frac{1}{x}$. Is there any example where the function converges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example 1**

Take $f(x) = \frac{1}{x \ln x}$ as a counterexample. $f$ is monotonic by the way.

**Example 2**

The integral will always be divergent as $f(x) \gt 1/2$ for $x$ large enough.

Comment: Thank you. Why f(x)>1/2 means the integral should diverge?

Comment: Because $f(x) \ge 1/2$ on $[a, \infty)$ implies $f(x) \ge f(a) + \frac{x-a}{2}$ for any $x \in [a, \infty)$